# Need to get most recent added record where certain columns are duplicate from a table

Tags: sql, database, duplicates

I need to query a table using T-SQL, where each entry has a unique id. Certain columns are duplicates, and of each of those duplicates I only need to select just the most recent added row.

Table:

```
id GUID,
columnA NVARCHAR,
columnB NVARCHAR,
email NVARCHAR,
isPublic BIT
```

Data Example:

```
id     | columnA     | columnB     | email     | isPublic
---------------------------------------------------------
guid1  | abcd        | efgh        | ab.ef@x.x | 1
guid2  | xxxx        | yyyy        | x.y@z.com | 0
guid3  | abcd        | efgh        | ab.ef@x.x | 0
```

Result Example:

```
id     | columnA     | columnB     | email     | isPublic
---------------------------------------------------------
guid3  | abcd        | efgh        | ab.ef@x.x | 1
guid2  | xxxx        | yyyy        | x.y@z.com | 0
```

Comment: How to know which is the most recent record?

Comment: Why not? In my view I do get the most recent record, what's confusing you? Maybe I can clarify. See above for updated version, I adapted it to use GUIDs now, as that's more correct for my example. Mind that I can't tell from the id's (guids) which one was more recently added. I can only see this because of the data in the other columns in my example at the office.

Comment: @YvesSchelpe . . . SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  You need to have information about ordering as a separate column, such as an id or created-at column.

Comment: @Gordon I feared as much, there's no way to track it in another way? I have no control over the table I'm querying, as it's from another product. I can't add triggers or other stuff to it thus :(

Comment: PS, @GordonLinoff, see anwser below, where ROW_NUMBER is used. Wouldn't that be a good indicative number to see which one was added first/last? Or doesn't SQL server capture which record was added anywhere? Otherwise I might have a problem indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**`ROW_NUMBER`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) for this:

```
SELECT id, columnA, columnB, email, isPublic
FROM (
  SELECT id, columnA, columnB, email, isPublic,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY columnA, columnB 
                            ORDER BY id DESC) AS rn
  FROM mytable) t
WHERE t.rn = 1
```

Comment: Actually, `guid3` will be ranked before `guid11` . Change it to `ORDER BY LENGTH(ID),ID DESC`

Comment: for now this seems to work, as for the guids, they're "0A8409D9-C5CE-4CE3-9AAC-936B9FE48234" not "guidx" and they don't represent date & time when something was posted. In fact, I don't need them in the end result at all, for now.
PS: does ROW_NUMBER represent a good indicative number which row was inserted first?

Comment: This orders by the `id` column, which I though the OP did not want (whether ascending or descending).